# Spark dataframe to dict with set

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having an issue with the output of my spark dataframe. The file can range from few GB to 50+GB

```
SparkDF = spark.read.format("csv").options(header="true", delimiter="|", maxColumns="100000").load(my_file.csv)
```

This give me the correct DF that I want. But as per requirement I need to have as key the column name and all the values in a set related to that key.

For example:

```
df = {'col1': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'col2': ['Jean', 'Cecil', 'Annie', 'Maurice'], 'col3': ['test', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc','ddd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Should give me at the end:

```
{'col1': {'1', '2', '3', '4'},'col2': {'Jean', 'Cecil', 'Annie', 'Maurice'},'col3': {'test', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc','ddd'}
```

I've implemented the following:

```
def columnDict(dataFrame):
    colDict = dict(zip(dataFrame.schema.names, zip(*dataFrame.collect())))
    return colDict if colDict else dict.fromkeys(dataFrame.schema.names, ())
```

However, it returned me a dict with a tuple as value and not a set as I require.

I would like either to convert the tuple in the dictionary into a set or just directly get a dictionary as a set as an output of my function.

EDIT:

**For the full requirements:**

Beside the dictionary mentioned above, there is another one that contains similar data for checking.

Means that the file that I load to a spark DF and transform into a dictionary contains data that must be checked against the other dictionary.

The goal is to check every key from my dict (the loaded file), against the check dictionary, first to see if they exist, then if it exist to check if the values of the keys are a subset of the check values.

If I load the check data in a dataframe it would look like this : (note that I may not be able to change the fact that it's a dict, I will see if I can modify from dict to spark df)

```
df = {'KeyName': ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], 'ValueName': ['1, 2, 3, 4', 'Jean, Cecil, Annie, Maurice, Annie, Maurice', 'test, aaa, bbb, ccc,ddd,eee']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
print(df)


      KeyName                                    ValueName
0    col1                                   1, 2, 3, 4
1    col2  Jean, Cecil, Annie, Maurice, Annie, Maurice
2    col3                  test, aaa, bbb, ccc,ddd,eee
```

So at the end, the data in my file should be a subset of a row that have the same KeyName as my dict.

I'm slightly stuck with legacy code and I'm little bit struggling to migrate it to spark databricks.

EDIT 2:
hopefully this will work. I uploaded the 2 files with modified data:
https://filebin.net/1rnnvqn2b0ww7qc8

FakeData.csv contains the data that I loaded on my side with the above code and must be a subset of the second one.
FakeDataChecker.csv contains the data that is the actual full set available

EDIT 3:
Forgot to add that all empty string in the FakeData should not be taken in account as well as the one in FakeDataChecker

Comment: This is pretty much counter intuitive to use Spark for distributed computation but that you require to use Sets and Dicts (data structures that aren't distributed, so your computations won't be optimized). Why do you need to retrieve all your data from an optimized Spark Dataframe to a dict which will only result in Out Of Memory Error on your machine ?

Comment: Could you elaborate what are your requirements and what do you want to achieve with your data ? Especially why don"t you only use Spark DataFrames but need sets and dicts ?

Comment: I have updated the requirements. Also, yes, I failed to mentioned that I'm working on migrating legacy code which I don't know much about yet and it's being migrated from single node non-pandas to Azure databricks. Someone before me ran the legacy code on databricks and he got quite a lot of Out of Memory..

Comment: Alright then, can you post a fake example of your data from your text files. Not from a pandas dictionnary or dict.
And is the dictionnary data used for the check come from some txt files also ? If so, can you also send a fake example of the raw txt file
We're going to forget and put aside all pandas / dict logic, and just base ourselves on Spark

Comment: Because I have some trouble to guess what are the KeyName and ValueName values format in your text files that you have to load. It would be helpful to have a fake data extract from the text files directly.

Comment: I've added the files that must be loaded and processed within the new architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure I have understood your usecase perfectly. But let's try with a first draft.

From what I'm understanding, you have a first file with all your data. And a file checker with keys that you need to have in the data foreach column. And additional keys present in the data should be filtered out.

This could be done with inner join between your initial data and the data checker. If there aren't too many keys in the data checker, Spark should automatically broadcast the data checker dataframe for optimized joins.

Here is the first draft of the code, this isn't yet completely automated waiting for your first questions and remarks.

### First let's import the needed functions and the data:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import Window

spark.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")

data = (
    spark
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .options(header=True, delimiter="|", maxColumns="100000")
    .load("FakeData.csv")
    .na.drop()
)

data_checker = (
    spark
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .options(header=True, delimiter="|", maxColumns="100000")
    .load("FakeDataChecker.csv")
    .na.drop(subset=["ValueName"])
)
```

We drop null values as you need, you can specify the wanted columns with the `subset` keyword

### Then let's prepare the join dataframes

```py
data_checker_date = data_checker.filter(col("KeyName") == "DATE").select(col("ValueName").alias("date"))
data_checker_location = data_checker.filter(col("KeyName") == "LOCATION").select(col("ValueName").alias("location"))
data_checker_location_id = data_checker.filter(col("KeyName") == "LOCATIONID").select(col("ValueName").alias("locationid"))
data_checker_type = data_checker.filter(col("KeyName") == "TYPE").select(col("ValueName").alias("type"))
```

We need to alias the column during the joins to avoid duplicated column names. And we specify the case sensitive option for when we drop the columns, so that we don't drop the initial ones in CAPS.

### Finally we filter out, through inner join all keys not present in the data checker:

```py
(
    data
    .join(data_checker_date, data.DATE == data_checker_date.date)
    .join(data_checker_location, data.LOCATION == data_checker_location.location)
    .join(data_checker_location_id, data.LOCATIONID == data_checker_location_id.locationid)
    .join(data_checker_type, data.TYPE == data_checker_type.type)
    .drop("date", "location", "locationid", "type")
    .show()
)
```

In next steps, we can automate this through retrieving the distinct keyNames of the columns (e.g.: "DATE", "LOCATION", etc...) So we can don't have to copy paste the code 4 times or X times in the future.

Something in the line of:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set

distinct_keynames = data_checker.select(collect_set('KeyName').alias('KeyName')).first()['KeyName']

for keyname in distinct_keynames:
    etc... implement the logic of chaining joins
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I'm actually getting close with your part. Also, as you guessed, the KeyName list is not static and some files can have quite a lot  of them. And you pointed out how to make it dynamically. The only thing I'm not sure I explained correctly thought, is that data in FakeData must be a subset of the content of FakeDatachecker. The goal of a check is to raise an error if the value exist for a key in FakeData but does not exist in FakeDataChecker. Would it be possible to have a right join instead ? And if it's empty I can be assured that data is an actual subset ?

Comment: Hmm maybe you would rather need a left anti join ? So you would retrieve every line of data present in FakeData but not in the FakeDataChecker. See the docs ref here, we could specify a `how` keyword and apply an anti join pattern https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Comment: Just had a look, sounds great. Thanks a lot for your help.